# How to Tranfer MP3 files or Video files using Python?

Tags: python, file, sockets, transfer

I'm transferring the text file from the server to client using socket in python.
Can i use the same code to transfer the Mp3 files or Video files?

```
import socket

s=socket.socket()
host=socket.gethostname()
port=8080
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)
print(host)
print("Waiting or incoming connection")
conn, addr = s.accept()
print(addr,"Has connected to server")

filename=input(str("Please enter the file name:"))
file=open(filename,'rb')
file_data=file.read(1024)
conn.send(file_data)
print("Data has been send successfully")
```

Comment: you can send whatever you like. For socket all is only bytes and it doesn't care what you send. You have to only send it encoded to bytes, not string.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: BTW: socket is low level object and it is very primitive and it doesn't care if you send all data. And it can send data partially so receiver never know if it get all data or not. You should first send information (with constant size) how much data you will send and then receiver has to first get this information (with constant size) and then it  may check if it get all data or if it has to wait for more.

Answer (score 2):

The sockets library doesn't care what you send as long as it's in bytes.
For this task though, I would recommend that you use FTP. It is a protocol used for file transfers. Python has a preinstalled library called ftplib that makes things much easier. [This](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html) is a good place to start.

Happy learning!